# Is there a word that can replace the slang "broken"?

Tags: word-choice

In various internet contexts and games, being "broken" means that you/something somewhat defy common sense by being stupidly powerful. Is there a more "proper" word that is equivalent to "broken"?

ie:

> That sword was so broken because it killed everyone in one hit.

Is there a certain word that can take the place of "broken" in the sentence without changing how the sentence is structured?

Comment: (Really? You call something _broken_ if it is "stupidly powerful"? Like _ill_ means "way cool/totally bitchin'"? That's a new one that should definitely be reported to the OED. ) That being the case, _overpowered_ could NOT possibly be a synonym.  _Overpowering_ might be.  Oh, I get it, you use those backwards too!  I guess I need to pay less attention to actual English, and more to the Alice in Wonderland of gamespeak, in which anything can mean the opposite of what it means in English.

Comment: In my experience, "broken" would refer to the physics of the game being broken, rather than that an object was necessarily overpowered.  So if a bazooka did little damage, or a handgun blew holes in walls, the weapon could be said to be "broken".  Hence, it does indeed mean something that defies common sense, but not necessarily in the sense of being stupidly powerful.
I've put this in a comment rather than an answer as I don't have an answer to the actual question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gaming contexts, the most common and appropriate term is
***overpowered***, often abbreviated to ***OP***.

From the [Wikipedia article on balance in gaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_(game_design)%23Overpowered), for example:

> ### Overpowered
>
> **Overpowered** (often abbreviated to **OP**) is a common term referring to a perceived lack of game balance. It is often used when describing a specific class in an RPG, a specific faction in strategic games, or a specific tactic, ability, **weapon** or unit in various games. For something to be deemed overpowered, it is either the best choice in a disproportionate number of situations (marginalising other choices) and/or **excessively hard to counter by the opponent** compared to the effort required to use it.